# Why does my desktop background keep changing?

Tags: xubuntu, desktop-background, flickr

I am running Ubuntu 10.04. I installed Xubuntu but I'm using the Gnome desktop. Recently my desktop started changing, downloading random pictures from somewhere. I don't remember installing an application to do this, but I must have. Unfortunately I don't remember what its name is.

Does this behavior ring any bells? Alternatively, what can I do to identify which application is doing this? (There isn't anything unusual in my Startup Applications.)

Comment: In the background chooser have you selected one that looks like a stacked deck of cards? There are two different kinds of pictures for the chooser, one is static images and one looks like a stack of pictures, almost the same. Check that you didn't pick one of those first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot that I had installed [Webilder](http://www.webilder.org/), which pulls photos from Flickr and webshots.